# Need help debugging Tomcat 7 application error

Tags: spring, tomcat7

**UPDATE**: This appears to be caused by the order in which spring beans are discovered and initialized. It's still unknown why the servers are detecting the beans in different orders, but gives me path to fix this.

I've run into a puzzling problem trying to deploy a WAR to Tomcat 7 (AWS OpsWorks, Ubuntu 12.04, Tomcat 7.0.26, OpenJDK 1.7.0_65):

After deploying the WAR, Tomcat immediately reports an error initializing the context due to a spring autowire exception in the application I'm deploying. "org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field...".

The issue is that this WAR works just fine on every other server I've loaded it on. I've even copied the unpacked webapps app directory (from the impacted server) onto another server with the same java and tomcat version with no issues.

Restarting the server, redeploying, and restarting tomcat doesn't seem to have any effect. Keeps giving me the same spring application error.

Any recommendations on how to debug this? The standard Tomcat log file with FINE output settings doesn't provide much detail besides the application's spring error.

```
ERROR [pool-2-thread-1] (ContextLoader.java:331) - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'emailTemplateService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private eco.domain.delivery.TemplateRepository eco.service.delivery.EmailTemplateService.emailtemplateRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [eco.domain.delivery.TemplateRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=EmailTemplateCrudMemRepository)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:326)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:725)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:649)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1581)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private eco.domain.delivery.TemplateRepository eco.service.delivery.EmailTemplateService.emailtemplateRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [eco.domain.delivery.TemplateRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=EmailTemplateCrudMemRepository)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:542)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:323)
        ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [eco.domain.delivery.TemplateRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=EmailTemplateCrudMemRepository)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1261)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1009)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:904)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
        ... 28 more
Nov 12, 2014 12:19:00 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
```

Comment: Can you provide the whole error message to help debug the issue

Comment: Sure, I've added the error to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue seems to be with your emailTemplateService.

Key message:

```
No qualifying bean of type [eco.domain.delivery.TemplateRepository]
```

Make sure your auto scan is picking up the relevant annotations.

Check out your whole email service line to ensure you have right annotations, let me know if this doesn't help.

Comment: That was my first guess, but the application starts up without this error on every other server I've tried. (even copying the exact unpacked webapps app directory to another server didn't replicate the issue).

Comment: If your annotations are correct and being picked up fully then you need to revisit your tomcat configuration as something could be missing. Are you using IDE to confiure and manage your tomcat server or manually doing the changes *.conf files and such?

Comment: I'm using AWS OpsWorks to manage the configuration and deployment. Using the standard out-of-the-box chef recipes included. I don't know where else to check besides the tomcat configuration files. Everything seems to match between to the two servers (/etc/tomcat7/*).

Comment: Found something interesting. I was able to get more logging info out of the application. It looks like the ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider class identifies the candidate component classes in a different order between the servers. On the server that's not working, it attempts to inject a bean that hasn't been created yet, based on the order.

Comment: Which would mean the above problem will occur if its trying to use a bean that is non-discovered yet.

Comment: Alright, so for an unknown reason the ordering of the bean discovery is different between servers. I think that's enough to solve this problem - thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to compare the ***server.xml*** environment configuration of your server and some working instance, if everything else is 'the same' you should find something missing there ...

Comment: Thanks, I just tried comparing the server.xml files, but there was no difference. Any other ideas?

Comment: I also tried comparing all of the files in the /var/lib/tomcat7/conf folder.. no luck.